# Facing issue with authorizing a Google Script I created

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, permissions, google-oauth, http-status-code-400

I have created a Google Scripts project that helps me manage my emails via labels and archiving. Through the interface at https://script.google.com/ I created an automatic trigger which worked like a charm for years! But it suddenly stopped working, and is now asking me to "authorize it".

When I click "**Review Permissions**" I land on a Authorization Error screen saying:

```
Error 400: policy_enforced

Request Details
access_type=offline
login_hint=frederic.mouniguet@gmail.com
hl=en_GB
response_type=none gsession
redirect_uri=https://script.google.com/oauthcallback
state=3722022919321157632
client_id=25559023822-v3uagu5v2htlkk4nepkpuqpkeh9ncnbm.apps.googleusercontent.com
prompt=consent
scope=https://mail.google.com/
```

I want to specify I do not own a Google Suite account, and therefore I cannot log into admin.google.com

Any help very much appreciated.

Attachment: screenshot of the popup error window[image]

Comment: Feels like Google is finding new ways to screw over apps script users.

Comment: Did you enable [Advanced Protection](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7519408) for your account? Could you share the project's code?

Comment: I have contacted Google Support on this particular Advanced Protection issue. Their response is to file a ticket in "Send Feedback" and it might help to solve this issue in the future. So please file your ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Iamblichus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10612011) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63647691/facing-issue-with-authorizing-a-google-script-i-created/63674092#comment112589686_63647691), [This is documented in the FAQ](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7539956):

> Apps Script may be blocked

> > If you're enrolled in Advanced Protection, Apps Script can be used. If scripts request access to certain data in your account, like emails, documents, or photos, they may be blocked.

Comment: This was it indeed! Simply had to disable the Advanced Protection in my Google settings to allow the Google Script again. Thank you.